# Are track and trail referring to different kind of footpaths in Australia?

Tags: australia, driving

When looking at maps, in Australia (at least in NSW state), some footpath are marked name as "trail" (e.g. https://goo.gl/maps/QWfxzDFjfrvBdtjcA) and some are named "track" (e.g. https://goo.gl/maps/YRfP1KoLZWFFqhYu5). If they refer to different kind of footpaths, have they officially been defined by authorities?

Comment: I'd be interested to find out if there is anything official. With a track, I'd check if they mean a walking track or a 4WD track, whereas with a trail I'd expect it to be for walking only.

Answer (score 3):

The endpoints of the trail and track you are linking to can be seen on Google Street View, so why not take a look for yourself? The trail is a dirt road closed off by a gate and the track is a narrow foot path.

But to quote Wikipedia:

> In Australia, the term track can be used interchangeably with trail,
>   and can refer to anything from a dirt road to an unpaved pedestrian
>   path.

Comment: As Jack said: "There's a track winding back to an o-old fashioned shack, 
Along the road to Gundagai "

Comment: thanks, I need a recourse supporting your definition.

Answer (score 2):

The standard on this would be the Australian/New Zealand Standard AS/NZS 4819:2011 *Rural and Urban Addressing*, which has been adopted by the [Intergovernmental Committee on Surveying and Mapping](https://www.icsm.gov.au/about).

The Standard is not freely available online, but parts of it have been republished by government authorities as part of their naming policy, e.g. the NSW Geographical Names Board's [Address Policy](https://www.gnb.nsw.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/223346/NSW_Address_Policy_and_User_Manual.pdf).  "Track" and "trail" are defined as follows:

> **Track** - Roadway with a single carriageway. A roadway through a natural bushland region. The interpretation for both Track and Trail is limited to roadways, whereas in many areas (e.g. Tasmania) these are often associated with walking rather than vehicular movement.
>
> **Trail** - See *Track*.

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly, the definition of  "track" implies that it's same as "trail" (*... for both track and trail...*"), but it does not mention the difference.